# Spnego asking for credentials when IP address is used in URL

Tags: spnego

I have configured spnego to work with tomcat server. It's working perfectly fine when I use computer name in the URL i.e. mycomuptername:8080/tools, it automatically authenticates the user and doesn't ask user for the credentials.

When I use ip address instead of computer name in URL i.e. http//10.0.0.0:8080/tools it asks users for the credentials every time user accesses the page.

I have been trying to find the solution for sometime now and have found out that this is happening because of enhanced security in IE which treats any url that has dot in it as internet site and not as local intranet site.

I tried adding the ip address in the zone sites for local intranet site settings in IE but that didn't work.

As explained in the below URL tried suppressing security but that didn't work.
http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1195402&tstart=0

I even installed IE 8 but having same issue on IE 8 as well.

Is there anyway to get spnego working with IP address without user needing to enter credentials.

Thanks,
Ankur.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have created a service principal in the AD which represents the tomcat server (something like **HTTP/yourcomputername@YOUR.DOMAIN.COM**). Because the client requests a TGT from the AD and the browser (IE) assumes the service principal name from the URL for the specific service (**HTTP/ + server_host + @YOUR.DOMAIN.COM**), the URL needs to correlate with the service principal account name in the AD.

Short: It isn't possible to do that via IP in Internet Explorer. Use Firefox!